# Dynamically connect to any database during runtime in Java Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, api, spring-mvc

I would like to know, is there any possible way to connect to any database during the runtime of a Java Spring Boot application? I am going to use database information from the user (from frontend).

Comment: when else would you connect to a database?

Comment: @Stultuske I don't want to configure database statically. When the application starts needs to get database configurations from users and connect during the runtime

Comment: yes, I understand that. And, when if not during run time would you else connect to a database? What is stopping you from creating your datasources from input you get from your user?

Answer (score 0):

I know something alternatively related to this,

AbstractRoutingDatasource: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source